# Oniony coleslaw

Tags: flavor

I have already made my coleslaw and the onion red onion it is too strong I want to tone it down as I said I've already made the salad do you have any suggestions on what to add to the coleslaw to tone it down

Comment: How long have you let the stuff age? Finely diced onion in coleslaw mellows over a period of hours; big chunks, not so much.

Comment: You didn't mention what kind of coleslaw you made. Is it one with a clear or a creamy dressing? Sweet, savory, or vinegary? Does it contain apple? If not, you might want to finely dice a sweet, tangy apple such as a Pink Lady or a Honeycrisp and mix it in. The apple soaks up a lot of onion taste, and it compliments most coleslaws.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment recommends, waiting will cause the strength of the onions to mellow.

If that's not enough, and you can't pick them out, the only other option is to increase the other ingredients.